# autoComplete "on" not working in ReactJs form

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui

I have below form in react for which i need to implement "autoComplete="on" so that next time if users want to input same value, it should be suggested as auto complete.Below is my code

```
<form className={classes.container} noValidate>
  <Grid container item xs={12} alignItems="center">
    <TextField
      id="outlined-bare"
      className={classes.textField1}
      defaultValue=""
      margin="normal"
      variant="outlined"
      autoComplete="on"
      InputProps={{ style: { height: 40 } }}
      onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 'Name')}
    />
  </Grid>
```

The component is being rendered is Chrome browser. What's wrong or missing here?

Comment: Add `name` input attribute - it helps to recognize what should be auto-filled.

Comment: which library are you using ? material ui ?

Comment: @Raju Yes, its Material ui

Comment: @Jax-p Added `name` but still its not working

Comment: It's a mystery how chrome's autoComplete works. I can't stop it from showing up, and you can't make it show up.

Comment: this is related to the version issue, i also got this error back then , which version you on ?

Comment: @Raju Its `@material-ui/core": "^4.4.0`

Comment: @VaibhavVishal Yes, this is why i love coding!!!

Comment: did you get any result ?

Comment: @Raju nope, its still not working

Comment: https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/ see this lara ,

Comment: This React issue might be why: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15739

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code below. You can add `autoComplete="on"` in form tag.

```
<form className={classes.container} noValidate  autoComplete="on">
  <Grid container item xs={12} alignItems="center">
    <TextField
      id="outlined-bare"
      className={classes.textField1}
      defaultValue=""
      margin="normal"
      variant="outlined"
      autoComplete="on"
      InputProps={{ style: { height: 40 } }}
      onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 'Name')}
    />
  </Grid>
</form>
```

Comment: That did not do anything for me